# Insert syntax error in oledbconnection

Tags: c#, syntax-error, sql-insert, oledbcommand

What is the problem in this code?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= kalanum; i++)
{
    foreach (Control ctr in panel1.Controls)
    {                       
        if (ctr is TextBox && ctr.Name == i.ToString())
        {
            int kalaid = int.Parse(((TextBox)ctr).Text);
            oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", kalaid);
        }
        else if (ctr is TextBox && ctr.Name == "tbxfee_" + (i.ToString()))
        {
            int fee = int.Parse(((TextBox)ctr).Text);
            oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fe", fee);
        }
        else if (ctr is TextBox && ctr.Name == "tbxnumber_" + (i.ToString()))
        {
            int number = int.Parse(((TextBox)ctr).Text);
            oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", number);
        }            
    }

    oleDbCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO fackala(factornum,kalaid,fee,number) values(@f,@k,@fe,@n)";
    oleDbConnection1.Open();
    oleDbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    oleDbConnection1.Close();            
}
```

All columns in my access file are numbers. When I insert all dates in the form and send the form, it shows:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: where is **@f** param?

Comment: it is before for loop!

Comment: @RezaZamani: Then you should have included it in the question... please make sure that future questions contain all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here:

- You're using four parameters, but only specifying 3 of them. (Comments suggest that you're specifying the other one outside the loop)
- On any one iteration you're only populating at most *one* of the parameters - what do you expect the values of the others to be?
- You're trying use named parameters with `OleDbConnection`. From the [`OleDbConnection.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters) documentation:

  > The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Comment: what should i do now?
id dont understand, because i am new!

Comment: @RezaZamani: You should use positional parameters, as per the documentation. Follow that link for more details.

Comment: @RezaZamani: There are further issues I hadn't noticed before - I've updated my answer. I suspect you may actually only want *two* parameters...